# How to use SweetAlert with clipboard.js library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert, clipboard.js

I'm trying to use [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) with the [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) library.
I have tried simulating a click on a HTML button when the user confirm on SweetAlert, but it didn't work.

Here is what I've tried to do:

**My HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyBtn" data-clipboard-target="#info_block" onclick="copyText();">
    Copy Text!
</button>

<div id="info_block" name="info_block">
    Some example text.
</div>
```

**My JavaScript function:**

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

**And the structure of my SweetAlert:**

```
swal({
  title: "Copy the text?",
  text: "Are you sure you want to copy it to clipboard?",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, copy it!",
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(){
  $("#copyBtn").click(); // simulates click on html button.
  swal("Copied!", "The text has been copied.", "success");
});
```

It works fine without sweet alert, but it won't work simulating a click on the copy button, and I can't figure out a way to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this variant, the newer SweetAlert2.js can be used.

```js
function copyText(){

    var copy = $('.copy_text').val();
    $('.copy_text').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Text copied to clipboard',
        text: copy,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<input type="text" class="copy_text" value="Hello World!">
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sweet alert was calling `$("#copyBtn").click();` which I am not sure is necessary.

In any case, you have set `onclick="copyText();"` in this button but never defined a `copyText` function.

Either define the function or remove the onclick attribute.

Here's working code with an empty `copyText` function defined.

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.log('Copied text: ' + e.text);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
function copyText() {

}

swal({
  title: "Copy the text?",
  text: "Are you sure you want to copy it to clipboard?",
  //type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, copy it!",
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(){
  $("#copyBtn").click(); // simulates click on html button.
  swal("Copied!", "The text has been copied.", "success");
}
);
```

```css
/*fit into snippet window*/
.sweet-alert { margin: auto; transform: scale(.75); }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@1/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyBtn" data-clipboard-target="#info_block" onclick="copyText();">
    Copy Text!
</button>

<div id="info_block" name="info_block">
    Some example text 
</div>
```

If you want to fire the alert on the button click then put the `swal` function inside of the function you defined in onclick:

Your sweet alert was calling `$("#copyBtn").click();` which I am not sure is necessary.

In any case, you have set `onclick="copyText();"` in this button but never defined a `copyText` function.

Either define the function or remove the onclick attribute.

Here's working code with an empty `copyText` function defined.

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.log('Copied text: ' + e.text);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});

function copyText() 
{
  swal({
      title: "Copy the text?",
      text: "Are you sure you want to copy it to clipboard?",
      //type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, copy it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function() {
      swal("Copied!", "The text has been copied.", "success");
    });
}
```

```css
/*fit into snippet window*/

.sweet-alert {
  margin: auto;
  transform: scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@1/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyBtn" data-clipboard-target="#info_block" onclick="copyText();">
    Copy Text!
</button>

<div id="info_block" name="info_block">
  Some example text
</div>
```